# Need to include the computer name in return values from Invoke-command so I know which computer the output is from

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a simple one line script that runs against a list of computers and returns the path of a file if the file contains certain text. This works.

I do however, need to run this against hundreds of computers and when I run it with Invoke-command, I don't know which computer has returned the path ... here is where I need your help please.

This is the command in its simplest form

```
invoke-command -computername $computers -erroraction silentlycontinue -scriptblock {get-childitem 'C:\' -rec -force -filter *.txt -ea silentlycontinue | foreach {select-string "<lookup.text>" $_} | select -exp Path}
```

The output comes in this form:

`c:\path\filename`

But there is no indication as to which server that path came from and I know that I am seeing multiple paths from multiple computers just from files I have dropped for my early testing.

Is it possible to amend the `-scriptblock` to get the computer name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you what you're looking for, there are a few considerations.

- If you don't use `-ExpandProperty` on your Script Block, the result of `Invoke-Command` should be an `object[]` that has the property `PSComputerName` attached to it. If you wish to use a specific property name instead, like in this example *"ComputerName"*, you can use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) in addition to the use of `-HideComputerName` switch.
- `Select-String` can be piped directly to `Get-ChildItem`, there is no need to use `ForEach-Object`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ChildItem 'C:\' -Recurse -Force -Filter *.txt -EA SilentlyContinue |
        Select-String "<lookup.text>" |
        Select-Object Path, @{
            Name = 'ComputerName'
            Expression = { $env:ComputerName }
        }
} -HideComputerName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: I new there was a `PSComputerName` I just couldn't figure out what I'd missed. The dangers of inherited code... Thank you I think that serves my purpose and certainly answers the question.

Comment: @sailingbikeruk i'm happy to help :) as long as you don't return an array of elements (like what was happening on your code, due to `-ExpandProperty`) and return an actual object instead you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Pscomputername is normally output by invoke-command with objects.  Just take out the "-exp" at the end.

```
# elevated
invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost { dir -r ..\foo *.txt -force -ea 0 | 
  select-string hi | select path }

Path                           PSComputerName RunspaceId
----                           -------------- ----------
C:\Users\admin\foo\file.txt    localhost      b7b6ca8b-f35e-41fc-ad98-ff2b6a51ae44
C:\Users\admin\foo\file.txt    localhost      2454784b-b56b-4e90-92fb-49b31dcc1745
C:\Users\admin\foo\file.txt    localhost      49e61d03-a68c-4308-a823-246cb3698f6a
```